# How can I make UploadFileAsync in Mega API

Tags: c#, api, file-upload

I am trying to upload file to me mega Account by C# App and I succeeded in upload but without any progress bar and the API has this method "**UploadFileAsync**" but I can't understand every parameter in this method.

This is from Object browser in VS

> IMegaApiClient.UploadFileAsync(string, CG.Web.MegaApiClient.INode,
> System.IProgress, System.Threading.CancellationToken?)
>
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<CG.Web.MegaApiClient.INode>
> UploadFileAsync(string filename, CG.Web.MegaApiClient.INode parent,
> System.IProgress progress,
> [System.Threading.CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null])
> Member of CG.Web.MegaApiClient.IMegaApiClient

**I know filename and INode parent but what should I write in `System.IProgress<double> progress` and `cancellationToken`?**

```
public uploadFileData uploadToMega(string megaFolderName, string megaFolderID, string filePathOnComputer, string newFileNameOnMega)
        {
            //Implemnt Struct
            uploadFileData myMegaFileData = new uploadFileData();

            //Start Mega Cient
            var myMegaClient = new MegaApiClient();

            //Login To Mega
            myMegaClient.Login(Userrrr, Passss);

            //Get All (File & Folders) in Mega Account
            IEnumerable<INode> nodes = myMegaClient.GetNodes();

            //Creat List Of All Folders In Mega Account
            List<INode> megaFolders = nodes.Where(n => n.Type == NodeType.Directory).ToList();

            //Choose Exist Folder In Mega Account By Name & Id
            INode myFolderOnMega = megaFolders.Where(folder => folder.Name == megaFolderName && folder.Id == megaFolderID).FirstOrDefault();
           

            //Upload The File
            //Normal Upload
            //INode myFile = myMegaClient.UploadFile(filePathOnComputer, myFolderOnMega);

            // Upload With progress bar
            INode myFile =  myMegaClient.UploadFileAsync(filePathOnComputer, myFolderOnMega, progressBar1, default());


            //Rename The File In Mega Server
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newFileNameOnMega))
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
                myMegaClient.Rename(myFile, newFileNameOnMega);
            }
            
            //Get Download Link
            Uri downloadLink = myMegaClient.GetDownloadLink(myFile);

            myMegaFileData.megaFileId = myFile.Id;
            Clipboard.SetText(myMegaFileData.megaFileId);
            myMegaFileData.megaFileType = myFile.Type.ToString();
            myMegaFileData.megaFileName = myFile.Name;
            myMegaFileData.megaFileOwner = myFile.Owner;
            myMegaFileData.megaFileParentId = myFile.ParentId;
            myMegaFileData.megaFileCreationDate = myFile.CreationDate.ToString();
            myMegaFileData.megaFileModificationDate = myFile.ModificationDate.ToString();
            myMegaFileData.megaFileSize = myFile.Size.ToString();
            myMegaFileData.megaFileDownloadLink = downloadLink.ToString();



            myMegaClient.Logout();



            return myMegaFileData;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.IProgress` is an interface used so that we can write custom progress types and interchange then with the ones built in.  It has one method `Report(T)` where `T` is an anonymous type.

This means you can write your own progress class but there is one already written in .NET that has that interface and since it qualifies let's use that one.  It found in the same namespace as `IProgress<T>` and is `Progress` and comes with a handy built in `ProgressChanged` event we can listen for. So in this first step code example I only introduce the progress.  Notice I replaced `ProgressBar` with the `progress` variable in code.

```
var progress = new Progress<double>();
progress.ProgressChanged += (s, progressValue) =>
{
    //Update the UI (or whatever) with the progressValue 
    progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(progressValue);
};

INode myFile = myMegaClient.UploadFileAsync(filePathOnComputer, myFolderOnMega, progress, default());
```

Now, I won't give you a lesson on `Task` but know that `Task` can be thought of in a lot of ways like threads but know that a `Task` doesn't always have to be a running thread. Anyway, the point is that we use a `CancellationToken` to signal canceling of a `Task`.  Since this `UploadFileAsync` is part of a different API we don't need to worry about handling the `CancelationToken` but we can supply one to try so that we can try and cancel the upload if we want to.  Just note that depending on the API and the `Task` canceled can potentially throw an error (usually `OperationCanceledException`) or similar.  Anyways, if you provided the token then also test canceling it to see how it all plays out.

In this code example I show you how you provide a `CancellationToken`.  *Remember, you can call cancel on this token from another button that might say something like (Stop Upload).*

So first, we will make a `CancellationTokenSource` and make it at the `class` level so that we can use it anywhere within our class.

```
private CancellationTokenSource uploadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Then before our `UploadFileAsync` call we need to make sure it has never been canceled, and if it has we should renew it.

```
if (uploadCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    uploadCancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
    uploadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
}

INode myFile = myMegaClient.UploadFileAsync(filePathOnComputer, myFolderOnMega, progress, uploadCancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

And... we can add a button click event or something to cancel the token if we want to.

```
private void CancelUploadButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!uploadCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        uploadCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Hopefully you understand a little more about what's going on and how to implement it.  Here just some mock code of the entire change via your example:

```
private CancellationTokenSource uploadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

public async Task<uploadFileData> uploadToMegaAsync(string megaFolderName, string megaFolderID, string filePathOnComputer, string newFileNameOnMega)
{
    //Implemnt Struct
    uploadFileData myMegaFileData = new uploadFileData();

    //Start Mega Cient
    var myMegaClient = new MegaApiClient();

    //Login To Mega
    myMegaClient.Login(Userrrr, Passss);

    //Get All (File & Folders) in Mega Account
    IEnumerable<INode> nodes = myMegaClient.GetNodes();

    //Creat List Of All Folders In Mega Account
    List<INode> megaFolders = nodes.Where(n => n.Type == NodeType.Directory).ToList();

    //Choose Exist Folder In Mega Account By Name & Id
    INode myFolderOnMega = megaFolders.Where(folder => folder.Name == megaFolderName && folder.Id == megaFolderID).FirstOrDefault();

    //Upload The File
    //Normal Upload
    //INode myFile = myMegaClient.UploadFile(filePathOnComputer, myFolderOnMega);

    //NEWLY ADDED
    var progress = new Progress<double>();
    progress.ProgressChanged += (s, progressValue) =>
    {
        //Update the UI (or whatever) with the progressValue 
        progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(progressValue);
    };

    //NEWLY ADDED
    if (uploadCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        uploadCancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
        uploadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    // Upload With progress bar
    INode myFile = await myMegaClient.UploadFileAsync(filePathOnComputer, myFolderOnMega, progress, uploadCancellationTokenSource.Token);

    //Rename The File In Mega Server
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newFileNameOnMega))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        myMegaClient.Rename(myFile, newFileNameOnMega);
    }

    //Get Download Link
    Uri downloadLink = myMegaClient.GetDownloadLink(myFile);

    myMegaFileData.megaFileId = myFile.Id;
    Clipboard.SetText(myMegaFileData.megaFileId);
    myMegaFileData.megaFileType = myFile.Type.ToString();
    myMegaFileData.megaFileName = myFile.Name;
    myMegaFileData.megaFileOwner = myFile.Owner;
    myMegaFileData.megaFileParentId = myFile.ParentId;
    myMegaFileData.megaFileCreationDate = myFile.CreationDate.ToString();
    myMegaFileData.megaFileModificationDate = myFile.ModificationDate.ToString();
    myMegaFileData.megaFileSize = myFile.Size.ToString();
    myMegaFileData.megaFileDownloadLink = downloadLink.ToString();

    myMegaClient.Logout();

    return myMegaFileData;
}

private void CancelUploadButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!uploadCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        uploadCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

I'm going to finish with one more bit of advice.  Since we have a class level disposable type (`CancelletionTokenSource`) then we should properly implement `IDisposable` in your class as well.  This is code showing ONLY the implementation of `IDisposable` and `CancellationTokenSource` and should be used however it fits best into your application.

If you're using your own class... (technically we should mark this sealed or provide and overridable `Dispose(bool)` to it but just for the sake of explanation it's like this.

```
public class Example : IDisposable
{
    private CancellationTokenSource uploadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public void Dispose()
    {
        uploadCancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    ~Example() => Dispose();
}
```

If you're in a WinForm or another inherited class that already has `IDisposable` implemented.

```
public class Example2 : Example
{
    private CancellationTokenSource uploadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public new void Dispose()
    {
        uploadCancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Ok, so finally I updated the `uploadToMega` method in the code above to read as a task.  This means that the calling method that uses `uploadToMega` will now also have to use `async` on the method signature and `await` on the call. 
Note: You can avoid this by keeping things the way they were prior to adding `async await` and simply adding `.Result` to the end of the `UploadFileAsync` method but understand that the thread now holds here until that completes.  So if it's the UI thread you will get complications and possibly lose the update to the progress bar.  The idea is you want this call to be asynchronous but for the sake of knowing here's the line below with `.Result;` added.

```
INode myFile = myMegaClient.UploadFileAsync(filePathOnComputer, myFolderOnMega, progress, uploadCancellationTokenSource.Token).Result;
```

If you would like, also update your question with the code that actually calls `uploadToMega` and I'll show you how we can update that portion as well.  In the end this change will be appreciated.

To better understand what's going on here I advise you to look into the `Task` type, understand how it works, and also look into the `async await` keywords which allow you to work with `Task` in an easier inline fashion.

Feel free to send me the whole project to michael_puckett_ii@hotmail.com and I'll update it, clean all the compiling errors, and leave some comments for you to help you understand the changes if you need to.

Comment: this is all good and i am going to understand it well  but i got this error 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State

Error CS1503 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Progress<int>' to 'System.IProgress<double>' WindowsFormsApplication1 C:\Users\EnGBassunY\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 75 Active

how i set it to System.IProgress<double>

Comment: @Eng.MohamedBassuny  No problem... This just means the progress in the ```UploadFileAsync``` is reported with a ```double``` instead of an ```int```.  I'm going to update the example now with ```double``` so look for it.

Comment: @Eng.MohamedBassuny Ok, I've updated the answer.  I made just changed ```Progress<int>``` to ```Progress<double>``` and in update to progressBar1 I added ```Convert.ToInt32(progressValue);```.

Comment: this error is gone but i got new one 

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<CG.Web.MegaApiClient.INode>' to 'CG.Web.MegaApiClient.INode'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) WindowsFormsApplication1 

C:\Users\EnGBassunY\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 75 Active

Comment: Well to be fair, I just scratched the code up here and never applied the code so I wasn't able to use intellisense or get errors.  You said it worked before so I assumed it was good to go except for the issue.  Hover your mouse over the ```UploadFileAsync``` method and see what the return type is.  It sounds like it's not returning ```INode```.

Comment: the code work without progress bar with method "UploadFile"
but when i try to use "UploadFileAsync" i got all this errors 
=====
when i remove "INode myFile =  " the error is gone but how i will receive the uploaded file data ?!

Comment: picture from mouse hover 
http://www4.0zz0.com/2018/05/05/11/159272010.png

Comment: and this link from Mega API Documentation
https://gpailler.github.io/MegaApiClient/api/CG.Web.MegaApiClient.MegaApiClient.html#CG_Web_MegaApiClient_MegaApiClient_UploadFileAsync_System_String_CG_Web_MegaApiClient_INode_System_IProgress_System_Double__System_Nullable_System_Threading_CancellationToken__

Comment: Ok, @Eng.MohamedBassuny I don't know why I didn't see this before; probably because it wasn't related to the question.  The method ```UploadFileAsync``` is a ```Task``` meaning it needs to be awaited; which basically notifies us when the operation is complete and returns the value to the calling thread.  To fix this we need to convert the entire method to a task ```public async Task<uploadFileData> uploadToMega…``` and then use the keyword ```await``` on the ```await myMegaClient.UploadFileAsync```.  I'm going to explain what this does and update my answer in code and at the bottom.

Comment: i Wait impatiently , i am Sorry to bother you

Comment: @Eng.MohamedBassuny NP, standby.  I'm working it now.  I had to run some errands for my wife.

Comment: @Eng.MohamedBassuny Ok, I've made the changes to the code and left more commentary at the bottom.

Comment: the code work well and the progress work  but after i add .Result; the GUI freeze :(
but it still upload the files to my account .. why it is too hard to use progress bar !

after i remove .Result; again and i want to get all uploaded file data in "struct" inside the method there is data for the file but i want the method return"struct" to use every single data in some thing

Comment: Yeah, like I said... Using .Result is not the right way to keep it asynchronous... If you can implement the entire pattern for the Task you'll get good results but you gotta think asynchronous on the UI and other components.

Comment: @Eng.MohamedBassuny If this addressed your issue and satisfies your question would you mind making it as answered?

Comment: i will be thankful if @Michael help me in another question  here 


[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394454/how-to-return-mega-account-information-form-mega-api)

Comment: @Eng.MohamedBassuny  NP, I've posted an answer to that question.  Please let me know if you need more help.