# How to return Mega Account Information Form Mega API

Tags: c#, api, file-upload

**I am new in C# and this is the first time I have used this API**

I want to get Mega Account Information from the API.

I can get (***TotalQuota*** , ***UsedQuota*** , ***AvailableQuota*** = "TotalQuota - UsedQuota") with the code blow (and I can convert it to GB).

```
MegaApiClient myMegaClient = new MegaApiClient();

public void megaAccLogIn(string megaAccUserName,string megaAccPassword)
{
    if (myMegaClient.IsLoggedIn == true)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        myMegaClient.Login(megaAccUserName, megaAccPassword);
    }
}

public struct AccountInfo : IAccountInformation
{
    public long TotalQuota { get; set; }
    public long UsedQuota { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IStorageMetrics> Metrics { get; set; }

    public long AvailableQuota;
}

public AccountInfo getfoldercount()
{
    AccountInfo myAccountInformation = new AccountInfo();

    megaAccLogIn(megaAccUserName, megaAccPassword);

    var myMegaClintGetAccInfo = myMegaClient.GetAccountInformation();

    //IEnumerable<IStorageMetrics> test = myMegaClintGetAccInfo.Metrics;




    myAccountInformation.TotalQuota = myMegaClintGetAccInfo.TotalQuota;
    myAccountInformation.UsedQuota = myMegaClintGetAccInfo.UsedQuota;
    myAccountInformation.AvailableQuota = myMegaClintGetAccInfo.TotalQuota - myMegaClintGetAccInfo.UsedQuota;
    myAccountInformation.Metrics = myMegaClintGetAccInfo.Metrics;

    return myAccountInformation;
}
```

this is the code to run the method

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myAccountInformation = getfoldercount();

    textBox1.Text = FormatBytes(myAccountInformation.TotalQuota) + "\r\n" + FormatBytes(myAccountInformation.UsedQuota) + "\r\n" + myAccountInformation.Metrics;

}
```

the picture [the error i got when i run "myAccountInformation.Metrics"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJz9E.jpg)

this is tha data i seek for [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sWvq.jpg)

i got this Exception [Trying the last foeach or the other way get this ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3tlo.jpg)

"**Metrics**" has some important data and I want to get it and I cannot implement the code to receive it as string.

I want to get (**FoldersCount** , **FilesCount** , **BytesUsed** , **NodeId**)

I have tried every searching for samples and found none.

I have this from "**Github**" but I still don't understand how to use it and what an ***Interface*** is. I don't need a lesson in C# just small insight about what is going on so I can continue.

[From This Page](https://github.com/gpailler/MegaApiClient/blob/master/MegaApiClient/Interface/IAccountInformation.cs/#L18)

If any one would help me I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you've provided to `MegaApiClient` you are not setting up your `AccountInfo` properly.  I could be wrong; this answer is based only on what you've provided and the link to the source `MegaApiClient`, which I assume is supposed to match.

I would first write my `AccountInfo` to match the `IAccountInformation` interface like so:

```
public struct AccountInfo : IAccountInformation
{
    public long TotalQuota { get; set; }
    public long UsedQuota { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IStorageMetrics> Metrics { get; set; }
}
```

Just changing that, I believe, will fix the error you're having.  In your code you're stating that `Metrics` is a `long` when in fact it needs to be `IEnumerable<IStorageMetrics>`.  If you need further explaining let me know and I'll gladly post / explain more.

Since you asked about insight about `Interface` I will try to explain it short and brief.

An `Interface` is basically a blue print of what an `object` should look like.  It explains features of the `object`.  For example:  in the `IAccountInformation` interface (via the link you provided) it states that an object will have at least a read only property `long TotalQouta`.  It also states there are two other properties `long UserQouta` and `IEnumerable<IStorageMetrics> Metrics`.

So if you make an `object` that uses this `Interface` you must implement those features to match the `Interface`.  You'll see I added the `Interface` to the `struct` for you and implemented it precisely.  (I did add setters to the properties as well since you are using them this way.)

Something interesting to take away from this is the use of polymorphism.  You can now access your object via the direct type or via the `IAccountInformation` interface as a type.  This is useful for methods that are only aware of the `Interface` and not the `Type` (or ```object````) that you're going to write on your own.

Another interesting thing to take away is how polymorphism is being used in the `IAccountInformation` `Interface` already.  The `property` `IEnumerable<IStoreMetrics> Metrics { get; }` is stating that any `Type` that derives from `IAccountInformation` will also have an enumeration of types that derive from `IStorageMetrics`.

When we look at `IStorageMetrics` (via the link you provided) you will see 4 properties (NodeId, BytesUsed, FilesCount, FoldersCount).

An `Interface` in code is like the ports on the back of an entertainment receiver, television, or computer. You have HDMI, RCA, Optic, USB, etc...  If you have a receiver that has RCA out and Optic out then you know you can plug either RCA cables into it or a fiber optic cable into it because that's the interface for the receiver.  The RCA jacks are meant to do something particular but the receiver has no idea what you're going to plug into it. It just knows it has to match that interface.  Code is the same way... We don't know who is using the `IAccountInformation` `Interface` but we do know that it will have the setup that `IAccountInformation` says and we can communicate to it via those.

**Ok, so you've updated the question some which is fine.  I'll leave what I have posted and post more here.**

Don't forget that `Metrics` is `IEnumerable<IStorageMetrics>` which means it's an enumeration of `IStorageMetrics` types.  (If it helps to visualize it think of `Metrics` as an array or list of `IStorageMetrics`.  `IEnumerable` just means that the type can be enumerated on.

Enumerations get used in many ways but one of the most common is in a loop such as a `foreach` loop.  So for example only, you could get the information from `Metrics` like so.

```
foreach (var storageMetric in myAccountInformation.Metrics)
{
    var bytesUsed = storageMetric.BytesUsed;
    var filesCount = storageMetric.FilesCount;
    var foldersCount = storageMetric.FoldersCount;
    var nodeId = storageMetric.NodeId;
    // do what you want with the info here
}
```

Another popular use of `IEnumerable` is using `System.Linq` which uses `IEnumerable` at the heart of all queries.
You could use linq, the way you had it earlier, like so...

```
 // The following will result in totalBytes being the sum of all Metrics
 var totalBytes = myAccountInformation.Metrics.Sum(storageMetric => storageMetric.BytesUsed);
```

So you could write the text with something along the lines of this:  (if the values you want are the sum of BytesUsed of course.)

```
var totalBytesUsed = myAccountInformation.Metrics.Sum(storageMetric => storageMetric.BytesUsed);
textBox1.Text = FormatBytes(myAccountInformation.TotalQuota) + "\r\n" + FormatBytes(myAccountInformation.UsedQuota) + "\r\n" + totalBytesUsed;
```

Does this make any sense?

Comment: first of all thank u for ur fast response 

second when i write "myMegaClintGetAccInfo.TotalQuota" it retern to me TotalQuota as long and i can use it as whatever i want 

but when i write "myMegaClintGetAccInfo.Metrics" it retern to me  like this pic [link](http://www7.0zz0.com/2018/05/17/18/509201172.jpg)

so how i can retern the FoldersCount ....etc as string or as anything i can use 

sorry to bother u and thanks for ur time

Comment: @Eng.MohamedBassuny Apologies but I can't get the pic at work.  Can you update the question with the information via text or code?

Comment: i added new pic for the data i expect to return from the myAccountInformation.Metrics

@Michael

Comment: @Eng.MohamedBassuny I've updated my answer, please see the bottom portion.

Comment: i got Exception from the code and i add pic for it and update the question  @Michael

Comment: @Eng.MohamedBassuny This just means there are no Metrics in there and it's null.  Can you send me the project and let me look at it.  I'm working with very little on my end.

Comment: the hole project in this link  [The Hole Project but add mega account haha](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16Z_tSh3ch9P4IPVNKoAYPpFWYCeXs-0r)
but how ther is no data to show "null" ?!

Comment: did u see the project? @Michael

Comment: @Eng.MohamedBassuny Not yet, apologies.  Sometimes I have free time and sometimes I have alot to do on my end. It may take some time so feel free to keep searching and digging but I'll try to get to it for you as soon as I get a few moments.